# How do I type a function's arguments but leave the return type "inferred"?

Tags: typescript

Below I have two functions `originalhelloWorld` which is untyped and `helloWorld` which has a type. You can see that the return of type o returns the "inferred" return type (what is the name for this), and type x returns "any".

How can I have the `ExampleFunction` type the functions arguments but leave the return type inferred? I've tried several combinations of generics, and nothing seems to work.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBOBLA5osBDANgCwKacxAHUFMATGAXhgApl5dco1kAuGaJMZGAHxgBGIEJlzowASioA+GAG8AUDGWIAZrSgBPAA64Q6+o2bcqlagHIhIsWHNSGUAK7wwMQ0xZLlD564AGeAQgMAAkcu7GyAC+fgpRCgpaunBUMABKTL4AKjq4ADxJeuoIKGhYgYQk8OTSCgD0dcoAegD8CXUAVDAAtL19-QODQ8MwHXUJhTAAogAe6AC22qIAYo5gwMzgqXQMHtzsnCx8gsKi4lKUsuKaCaCQsBXEpGTsswtLuKvrm67UO0YsC6yRTKGBqDS5fRuXaRUwWKxnWz2TIuaEA7heGA+VEBfCEULhGEsGJxCa5GAzVIZJwuHK6AqQ9SPKo1eqNGCtIA)

```
const originalhelloWorld = (greeting: string | boolean) => {
   if (typeof greeting === 'boolean') return greeting
   return `hello ${greeting}`
}

type o = ReturnType<typeof originalhelloWorld>
//  ^? type o = string | boolean

/* ------------------------------------ */

type ExampleFunction = (greeting: string | boolean) => any

const helloWorld: ExampleFunction = (greeting) => {
   if (typeof greeting === 'boolean') return greeting
   return `hello ${greeting}`
}

type x = ReturnType<typeof helloWorld>
//  ^? type x = any
```

Comment: Not possible if you want to keep the type annotation since type annotations effectively override the type if the original type is assignable to the new one.

Comment: If you would like, it is possible to use a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDRrOW) to type the parameters for you, while keeping the inference of the return type.

Answer (score 0):

The new `satisfies` operator in typescript 4.9 works:

[Playground Link:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBOBLA5osBDANgCwKacxAHUFMATGAXhgApl5dco1kAuGaJMZGAHxgBGIEJlzowASioA%20GAG8AUDGWIAZrSgBPAA64Q6%20o2bcqlagHIhIsWHNSGUAK7wwMQ0xZLlD564AGeAQgMAAkcu7GyAC%20fgpRCgpaunBUMABKTL4AKjq4ADxJeuoIKGhYgYQk8OTSCgD0dcoAegD8CXUAVDAAtL19-QODQ8MwHXUJhTAAogAe6AC22qIAYo5gwMzgqXQMHtzsnCx8gsKi4lKUsuKaCaCQsBXEpBTUNDtGLBeyisowahq5fRuXaRUwWKxnWz2TIuYEfbheGA%20WEBfCEULhEEsGJxKQQdDMCCqRC4CDTOaLFZrDaIcATXIwGapDJOFw5XQFQHqR5VGr1RowVpAA)

```
const originalhelloWorld = (greeting: string | boolean) => {
   if (typeof greeting === 'boolean') return greeting
   return `hello ${greeting}`
}

type o = ReturnType<typeof originalhelloWorld>
//  ^?

/* ------------------------------------ */

type ExampleFunction = (greeting: string | boolean) => any

const helloWorld = ((greeting) => {
   if (typeof greeting === 'boolean') return greeting
   return `hello ${greeting}`
}) satisfies ExampleFunction

type x = ReturnType<typeof helloWorld>
//  ^?
```